# What is wrong with this chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have downloaded this chrome extension https://github.com/jeffreyiacono/penalty-blox
When I load it via load unpacked extension it gives me this error
1.manifest_version key must be present and set to 2 
I solved it via adding manifest_version in manifest.json
2.After this when I reload it,The icon is coming but when I click on it nothing is working(looks like background.html is not working)
What changes should I do so that it workes perfectly?

Comment: Could you try installing it as a packed extension using [the provided link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/penaltyblox/ajoigckelmnkcjajbeinpkmbndeiokdg)? It might install properly that way.

Comment: Yes.If I install it via chrome store it is working perfectly.But I don't know why this is not working if I load it manually.

Comment: What did you set the `manifest_version` to in the `manifest.json` file?

Comment: I added this "manifest_version":2,

Comment: When I install it using the `manifest_version` set to 2, it shows an error in my extensions list: `There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
'background_page' requires manifest version of 1 or lower.` I think the extension may be out of date and not maintained on that repository any more, as using `manifest_version` set to 1 does not load.

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Comment: Well, why do you want to install it as unpacked instead of from chrome's web store in the first place? It seems to me like the unpacked version does not work because it is out of date, but the one on the web store works because it somehow does not need a manifest.

Comment: Solved it. replace popup with "default_popup" and using "background": {"page": "background.html"}

Comment: FYI, Chrome provides [Tutorial: Migrate to Manifest V2](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html).